# Add Google Play Services Wearable to Phonegap App?

Tags: android, cordova, wear-os

When I run my Phonegap App fails with this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I notice that this only happens when I add the Play Services part for wearables

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
```

I need it because I want to share DataItems between my PhoneGap app and an Android Wear App

This is my CordovaLib/build.gradle,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.2") {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        }
    } else if (gradle.gradleVersion >= "2.1") {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0+'
        }
    } else {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.0+'
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion cdvCompileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion cdvBuildToolsVersion
    publishNonDefault true

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.5.0'
}
```

Gradle console log:

```
Executing tasks: [:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:compileLint
:CordovaLib:copyDebugLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest
:CordovaLib:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:prepareDebugDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:prepareAndroidCordovaLibUnspecifiedDebugLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:checkReleaseManifest
:CordovaLib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:CordovaLib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42200Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava
Note: /Users/rubdottocom/Documents/AndroidStudio/TransportMe/platforms/android/src/de/appplant/cordova/plugin/localnotification/LocalNotification.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugSources
:preDexDebug
:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatHoneycomb;","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/app/NotificationCompatHoneycomb;"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 11.876 secs
```